# Enhance WSDL presentation with XSLT for wsdl which generates on the fly

Tags: web-services, xslt, soap, wsdl, jax-ws

I developed a small web service using JAX-WS. Now I need to add XSL to enhance WSDL presentation. I've found a great solution for this - http://tomi.vanek.sk/index.php?page=wsdl-viewer , but the problem is that my wsdl file is generating on the fly so I cannot add stylesheet directly to my wsdl. Is there some solution for this?

Comment: There is no requirement for XSLT to be added to the [original XML source as PI](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-stylesheet/), it is by en large only used in browsers. It is generally better to add the XML source as an argument to your XSLT processor, that way the XML content does not need to be changed (but I am unaware of the rest of your environment to whether this is feasible).

Answer (score 0):

You can store your WSDL file in WEB-INF/wsdl  and  specify its path in your "sun-jaxws.xml" file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <endpoints
     xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jax-ws/ri/runtime"
     version="2.0">
       <endpoint
     name="fromwsdl"
     interface="fromwsdl.server.AddNumbersPortType"
     implementation="fromwsdl.server.AddNumbersImpl"
     wsdl="WEB-INF/wsdl/AddNumbers.wsdl"
     service="{http://duke.example.org}AddNumbersService"
     port="{http://duke.example.org}AddNumbersPort"
     url-pattern="/addnumbers" />
    </endpoints>
```

Plz check below URL for WAR structure

https://jax-ws.java.net/nonav/2.2.1/docs/UsersGuide.html#1.0_Introduction